# lxde and internet connection lost after updating

Tags: networking, lubuntu, internet, gui, lxde

I have a Lubuntu installed on my vmware it was run perfectly untill I updated it then I started to  get the  lxde xsession problem and I lost the gui but I can read my files from command line  and I lost the access to the internet so i can't installing lxde gui using command line so what I do ?  to get the internet back i tried `sudo ifconfig <logical name> up`  the command worked but the internet connection still lost

Comment: You haven't given us much to work with.  What release of Lubuntu?  Do you, or can you assign a static ip address? can you ping your closest switch? or say google's dns (ie. `ping 8.8.8.8` without using DNS, or do you get issues only if you if try & use DNS, ie. `ping dns.google.com`) etc

Comment: @guiverc i get network unreachable with ping 8.8.8.8 
and name or service not known with ping dns.google.com and i have ubuntu 18

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 18, so do you mean Ubuntu Core 18? (an IoT intended version of Ubuntu which is *yy* in format) or something else.  Most standard desktop/server editions of Ubuntu are *yy.mm* in format (having multiple releases per year), and only special purpose releases are *yy* in format (like Ubuntu Core 18) having only a single release per year.

Answer (score 2):

this command fixed the internet disconnection problem for me `sudo dhclient <logical name>`

for me my logical name was ens33 `sudo dhclient ens33`

that's how to know you logical name 
use this command `sudo lshw -class network`

then to fix you internet connection

```
sudo dhclient <logical name>
```

then I used this command to install the gui to fix the xsession and lxde gui problem

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
```